Citar does not work with org-cite
I'm having trouble with citar in org-mode. With a simple .bib file, org-cite-insert works fine without citar, but whenever I set (org-cite-insert-processor 'citar), like explained here https://github.com/emacs-citar/citar?tab=readme-ov-file#org-cite , then org-cite-insert just says Aborted. I tried to debug using debug-on-entry for the function org-cite-insert, but that is just endless sequence of commands.

org - v9.6.15
citar - v20240419.2232
emacs v29.4

tried both on mac and ubuntu with the same result.
How could I continue, like get proper backtrace instead of message "Aborted"?
Update:
trying with edebug (edebug-defun), it gets to the choice in minibuffer, which shows References:  (0/1):, but there no matter if I try TAB, Enter or something else, it just gets aborted.

You might find edebug easier to use in this case.

@NickD Thanks, got edebug working better, but I end up in minibuffer, where debugger does not seem to work any more? Edited question description.

Try instrumenting the function org-cite-make-insert-processor for edebug. It is the only function I can see which raises a user error with an Aborted message. I have no idea how any of this works however, so this is just a guess.

@NickD thanks, that gets me a little further. (funcall select-key t) seems to return no values, and this is the same behaviour, that I get when calling citar-open directly, which is minibuffer with message References:  (0/85):, but the error with citar-open is No associated resources instead of Aborted. It is confusing still, because the 0/85 clearly shows that the correct bib file is being accessed.
